# Как сделать открытие modalView как в App Store используя SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

Подскажите, как можно реализовать открытие ModalView с анимацией как в Aplle App Store используя SwiftUI?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас верстка выглядит так:

```
    ZStack (alignment: .bottom){
        Image(category.Img)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        HStack{
            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                Text(category.Tag)
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                Text(category.Title)
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .lineLimit(3)
                    .lineSpacing(0)
                Text(category.Subtitle)
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                    .lineLimit(2)
            }.padding()
            Spacer()
        }.background(Color(red: 220/250, green: 220/250, blue: 220/250, opacity: 0.95))
    }

    .cornerRadius(10)
    .overlay(
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
            .stroke(Color(.sRGB, red: 150/255, green: 150/255, blue: 150/255, opacity: 0.1), lineWidth: 1))
        .padding([.top, .leading, .trailing])
```

Comment: [ВОТ](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2925473-ios-animation-tutorial-custom-view-controller-presentation-transitions)
Посмотрите, это туториал того что вам нужно !